# How can I send header message in Java?

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a request message like this, in SOAPUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    xmlns:service="www.xxxxx.xx">
<soapenv:Header>
  <service:SessionInfo>
    <service:UserPassword>?</service:UserPassword>
 </service:SessionInfo></soapenv:Header> 
<soapenv:Body>
 <service:Method1>
 <!--Optional:-->
 <service:Arguments>
    <service:Parameter1>?</service:Parameter1>
    <service:Parameter2>?</service:Parameter2>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <service:Parameter3>?</service:Parameter3>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <service:Parameter4>?</service:Parameter4>
 </service:Arguments>
 </service:Method1></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am having problem while sending header message of this wsdl in Java. I sent the request message in C# and SOAPUI successfully. I was able to view partial class in C# which is soapenv:Header in SOAPUI. I could not view partial class after importing wsdl in Java. Do I have to do something different in Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd use a library to invoke the SOAP endpoint such as axis2.

[This blog post](http://www.keith-chapman.org/2008/10/axis2-setting-custom-http-headers-on.html) shows how to set the headers using this library.

```
MessageContext responseMessageContext =
       MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext().getOperationContext().getMessageContext(
               WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_OUT_VALUE);
List headers = new ArrayList();
headers.add(new Header(HTTPConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING, "identity"));
responseMessageContext.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, headers);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added same code block in Java but I got this error: the method getCurrentMessageContext() is undefined for the type MessageContext. Although I imported the org.apache.axis.MessageContext.

Comment: Is there another solution for this problem without using axis2 library?

Comment: Yeah you can do it using JAX-WS but I'm not sure how you'd specify the header http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jax-ws/create-and-consume-web-service-using-jax-ws/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there is a link which belongs to author @Slim Ouertani and link is:http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-header-part-1-client but I could not apply it to my project.I just need a simple example. I could not adopt all the classes in that link to my project.